# P/Invoke C++ template<T> method from C#

Tags: c#, c++, templates, generics, pinvoke

I have defined in C++ function for external calls:

```
template<typename T>
void __declspec(dllexport) SwapMe(T *fisrt, T *second)
{
    std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;

    T temp = *first;
    *first = *second;
    *second = temp;
}
```

I want to use it in C# program. I've tried in this way:

```
unsafe class Program
{
    [DllImport("lib1.dll", EntryPoint = "SwapMe")]
    static extern void SwapMe<T>(T first, T second);

    ...
}
```

But, I'm getting such error:

***Generic method or method in generic class is internal call, PInvoke, or is defined in a COM Import class.***

Seems to be, that  Generic in C# is managed type and it's rather different stuff by architecture with unmanaged template in C++.

How can I use template method in my C# program?

Comment: That's not possible, templates do not have external linkage.  The closest you could get is C++/CLI code that uses the *generic* keyword.

Comment: @HansPassant What does it mean? Please explain me! Can I prepare manually with some binary serialization (or smth like that...) <T> in C++ for external linkage? thank you!

Comment: It means that it is utterly, completely, out of the question, not possible.  No point in trying to make it work, it will not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Template functions are not burnt into the binary by the C++ compiler. Only specialized versions are ever emitted. The C++ compiler logically clones the template definition and replaces `T` with whatever concrete type is wanted.

This means that you must create a specialized wrapper:

```
void __declspec(dllexport) SwapMe(int *fisrt, int *second) { //example
{ SwapMe(first, second); }
```

You can call this one from C#, But you cannot call the template version.

C++ templates and C# generics work very differently.

Comment: Seems to be, that it's the one of the main different between C++ templates and C# generics. But how can C++/CLI  work with it?

Comment: @OlegOrlov C++/CLI probably never violates the rules by placing restrictions. I'm not qualified to answer for sure but my guess would be that you can't call a template function with a generic parameter. It probably results in a compiler error.

Comment: But the <T> must have some default structure. Yes, C++ does replace it, but at the moment, when it wasn't replaced it must have some structure too. What's the structure of T before the replacement?

Comment: @OlegOrlov T really has no structure. How else would you explain that you can write `T x, y; return x == y;`? Not every type is comparable, and those that are might compare totally differently. For that reason this does not work with generics (but does work  in C++). This only works because T gets replace to an exact type at compile time.

Comment: ahhh... and generic is a real undefined structure which really lives in runtime time and which is getting result with reflection in runtime... Why doesn't C++ have such stuff? ( don't know about C++ 11 version, doesn't C++ support generics in 11? )

Comment: templates in C++ are just hints for the compiler how to compile like #define , but not another structure as generics in C#

Answer (score 0):

To add to the above, we recently went through this and used T4 (TextTransform.exe) to generate templates for the wrappers in C++.

To do this, we included a T4 file in the C++ project and for each combination of type args, generated a wrapper method around the C++ template method. The wrapper method was then exported.

Finally in C# we did the same, using T4 to generate a generic wrapper around the exported methods. This way you bridge the divide between .NET Generics and C++ templates while harnessing the full awesomeness of C++ Templates